# Regex for replacing two strings in the same line

Tags: java, regex, replace

For example I have this one line in a text file

```
Additional_Cost_utilities=(out.Utilities.Ener.Steam_cons.Value*0.056 + out.Utilities.Ener.Elec_cons.Value*0.09 + (STRING_NEW1*STRING_NEW2*0.003));
```

I need a regex to replace the tokens of STRING_NEW1 and STRING_NEW2 with some new strings. What regex could I use so that nothing else is edited in the line other than these two strings?

Edit: The strings to be replaced are different each time. So I just cant use replace. A stable regex is required to modify the STRING_NEW1 and STRING_NEW2 tokens independently of their content, which will be float numbers

The code I am trying to use to replace the strings in the specific line of a big coding part is the following. The regex needs to recognize the line and the tokens of the strings to be replaced. I hope this helps

```
try {
        Path path = Paths.get("read.m");
        Charset charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path), charset);

        content = content.replace("STRING_1_IN_THE_LINE", "new string1")
                .replace("STRING_2_IN_THE_LINE", "new string2");

        Files.write(path, content.getBytes(charset));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Simple exception handling, replace with what's necessary for your use case!
            throw new RuntimeException("Generating file failed", e);
         }
```

Comment: Can you guarantee those strings will not be present elsewhere in your line? If so, `someString.replace("STRING_NEW1", "foo");` would do it.

Comment: @Duncan Nope. And they change every time. So I need a stable regex to make them changeable

Comment: And what about the rest of the string? How much of that remains stable?

Comment: @Duncan I just have these two strings that i want to change no matter their context (literals or numbers). rest are just literals

Comment: What do you mean "just literals". Are you saying *everything* in that string is static (unchanging) except for those two tokens?

Comment: Sorry not literals, but integers long. Yes and everything else is static except these two tokens. @Duncan

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex , just read this line a String variable and call [String.replace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) method where the first param is the old String , and the second param is the new one. if you want to replace for example `STRING_NEW1` with an explicite string value then rty this :

```
String data="Additional_Cost_utilities=(out.Utilities.Ener.Steam_cons.Value*0.056 + out.Utilities.Ener.Elec_cons.Value*0.09 + (STRING_NEW1*STRING_NEW2*0.003));"
data=data.replace("STRING_NEW1","\"a new string value\"");
```

Comment: the STRiNG_NEW1 is different every time. So yes I do need a regex

Comment: They are numbers and they should change often in those tokens depending on some user input

Comment: @user3211165 sorry but you have to give more information so that we can help you.

Comment: No matter what string_new1 and 2 are I need a regex that will replace them with some new strings @Mifmif

Comment: The strings to be replaced will be numbers integers

Comment: @user3211165 if so , then try with `data=data.replaceAll("STRING_NEW\\d+","\"a new string value\"");`

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to replace `string1` and `string2`,

```
^(.*\+\s+\()([^*]*)(\*)([^*]*)(.*)
```

In the replacement part, instead of 3rd and fourth group you need to put the replacement string for string1 and string 2.

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hD7kM4)

Comment: Your regex seems to be working fine and does not require for me to know the string 1 and 2 to be replaced. However I do not get what you mean by "instead of 3rd and fourth group you need to put the replacement string for string1 and string 2." Can you please explain?

Comment: on the replacement part first put $1 represent group1 which matches all before the string1. And the second match is string1 instead of this you need to put the replacement string.The third group is *, so you have to put this. Fourth group represents string2, instead of this put the replacement string for string2. and add the last group with it. `$1foo$3bar$5`. I know only the regex but i don't know the coding part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.replace twice to keep two simple regex and make them more readable.

```
// Change WHATEVER1 for the 1st string you w
// Change WHATEVER2 for the 2nd string you want
String result = str.replace(" \\(\\w+\\*", "(WHATEVER1*")
                   .replace("\\*\\w+\\*0\\.003", "*WHATEVER2*0.003");
```

Comment: @user3211165 have you tried it? I tried and it worked